# Google Cloud API - Application Default Credentials

Tags: php, google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-api-php-client

I have the following code, modified from [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials):

```
        $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = "./[path].json";
        $_ENV["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "./[path].json";
        $_SERVER["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "./[path].json";

        $projectId = "[my project's ID']";
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
        $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/books']);
        $service = new Google_Service_Books($client);
        $results = $service->volumes->listVolumes('Henry David Thoreau');
```

Yet when I run it it returns the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'DomainException' with message 'Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information'
```

I have tried various configurations, for example changing the path of the file. As you see, I've also done the three different forms of variables that I could immediately think of (two environment, one not).

I'm not quite sure where to look next. Should I look into different ways of setting the environment variable or should I define the path in a different way? What are the correct ways of doing this? Is there any other reason for the error?

Comment: Where are you running the code from (eg. App Engine prod or dev, Compute Engine, locally)?

Comment: @Adam Locally, on a Windows / Apache system. However, I'm building for something that will run on a Linux / NGINX system.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to use `putenv()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php) instead of trying to use any of the methods you have used (`$_ENV` or `$_SERVER`).

Taken from https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/UPGRADING.md#google_auth_assertioncredentials-has-been-removed

```
// OR use environment variables (recommended)

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/service-account.json');
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
```

Comment: Please read “[How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)”

Comment: @fusion3k I can't see any issue with my answer. Okay, it's short, but they've asked "should I define the path in a different way?" and my answer shows how to define the path in a different way, thus answering the question. I believe my answer is self explanatory & does not require any further explanation. "Brevity is acceptable". I'm happy to hear how you think I could improve the answer though?

Comment: First of all: your answer has been reported by several users as ‘unclear’, so more that one think that it is not ‘self explanatory’. I can agree with you: for me - and maybe for the OP - the answer is self-explanatory, but this site is not chat-like, questions and answers exists also for future visitors. A better answer could be like “Your try to set environment variable is not valid, you have to use this syntax instead of... $_ENV means that... see the docs for more details... etc”. There are many way, but the “audience” wants more that one line of code.

Comment: @fusion3k Okay, all fair points & I've updated my answer. The link you first posted doesn't say any of that though, so if you've going to down vote people & request correct answers are deleted, maybe you could explain why first.

Comment: Thanks got the hint from this. But for laravel project I ended up adding GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/service-account.json to the .env file. Just giving it here so may other can get help.....

Comment: putenv() has been disabled for security reasons ... the irony

Answer (score 6):

I agree with the above answer, but only want to describe if user getting error in php using nlp google:

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

# Includes the autoloader for libraries installed with composer
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

# Imports the Google Cloud client library
use Google\Cloud\Language\LanguageClient;
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/home/sgupta/www/practise/nlp/google/cred.json'); //your path to file of cred
//$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
# Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
$projectId = 'nlp-project-nname'; //your project name

# Instantiates a client
$language = new LanguageClient([
    'projectId' => $projectId
]);

# The text to analyze
$text = 'Sachin Tendulkar';



# Detects the sentiment of the text
$annotation = $language->analyzeSentiment($text);
$sentiment = $annotation->sentiment();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($annotation); die;

echo 'Text: ' . $text . '
Sentiment: ' . $sentiment['score'] . ', ' . $sentiment['magnitude'];
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this one it's working for me

```
# Includes the autoloader for libraries installed with composer
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=../service-account.json');
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
$client->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
$token = $client->getAccessToken();
$accessToken = $token['access_token'];
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? Which parts are neccessary and why?

Comment: I used this way but $client->getAccessToken(); return an invalid token (it looks like 'abcxyz....' - the last characters is all 'dot dot dot'). Do you know why.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can define a path to your json file like this

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('/path/to/credentials.json');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the following array to your client

```
[
  'credentials' => json_decode(file_get_contents('path_to_your_file_.json')), true)
]
```

In my case its text to speech client, so it can be following

```
 $textToSpeechClient = new TextToSpeechClient([
        'credentials' => json_decode(file_get_contents('path_to_your_file.json')), true)
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Attempt to use the ImageAnnotator like below
When running the code, observe that you get an error:
Could not construct ApplicationDefaultCredentials**

**solution**

```
putenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/home/netwons/Downloads/AIz.json");
```

**but not work.
OS: Ubuntu
PHP version: 7.2.4
Package name and version: google/cloud-vision 0.19.1
this is code**

```
$imageAnnotator = new ImageAnnotatorClient();
//        $client->setAuthConfig('key.json');

        # the name of the image file to annotate
        $fileName = '2.png';

        # prepare the image to be annotated
        $image = file_get_contents($fileName);

        # performs label detection on the image file
        $response = $imageAnnotator->labelDetection($image);
        $labels = $response->getLabelAnnotations();

        if ($labels) {
            echo("Labels:" . PHP_EOL);
            foreach ($labels as $label) {
                echo($label->getDescription() . PHP_EOL);
            }
        } else {
            echo('No label found' . PHP_EOL);
        }
```